# Manually route a global keyboard shortcut to a specific application on Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an application (last.fm 1.5.4) that doesn't use global keyboard shortcuts, i.e. its shortcuts only work when the application has focus.

Is there a way of manually defining a global shortcut in windows7 that will be routed to the application, even when it doesn't have focus?

Answer (score 2):

Only to remark that [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), suggested by Botond Balázs, started as a fork of [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/).

AutoIt has continued to evolve even more, and may be more pleasurable for writing scripts.

Answer (score 2):

If we're all going the autohotkey route, let's give some **scripting help**!

[This](http://tadhg.com/wp/2007/03/23/autohotkey-script-for-lastfm/) script was reccomended by Lifehacker, and looks pretty good to me. Never used last.fm, so that's all I've got :)

Looks like it's a little complex, but if you simply paste that script into the top of a .ahk file (basically a text file with the extension .ahk), then you can use things like:

```
#p::ControlLastFM("Toggle")
```

to play/pause on Winkey (# is the winkey modifier) and P (p is p, any key will do :))

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to define a global shortcut, and bind it to a script that sends key presses to the window.